# Git Pull Request removes changes from another PR

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

Unfortunately, I can't post a link to a repo, but I'll do my best to explain what's my problem.

Let's say we have some repo **REP**. On **REP** we have **master** branch. From Jira, I create a new branch **A** and do some changes. Then I create a new **B** branch for another feature. I can't tell if this problem appeared while having 2 branches because that time I had about 6 different PR and don't know exactly the order of merging the PRs.

Some PR changed **MyFile.php** file (-2, +6), let's say it was **A** branch. When we look at BitBucket's PR diff we can see some sort of revert **MyFile.php** (-6, +2).  What's more interesting looking through all commits in **B** branch doesn't show these changes. All commits one-by-one and no changes in **MyFile.php**. Does anybody experience something similar to that?

Greets!

**Edit 1:**
I've rechecked and it seems this PR "reverts" more files, but still, I didn't touch them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok one easy way to solve this is Merge PR 1 (branch A) to master and then pull master and locally merge it to PR 2(branch B) and push the changes. Now you will see the changes in branch A(with commits) in PR 2 (branch B)

PR1-branchA
PR2-branchB
Branch to merge into - master

This is how your commands would look if you're doing the whole thing locally

```
git checkout master
git merge branchA
git checkout branchB
git merge master
git checkout master
git merge branchB
```

If you're submitting PR's in the remote

- Merge PR1 to master
- locally run `git pull origin master`
- then run `git checkout branchB`
- `git merge master`
- `git push origin branchB`
- merge PR2 to master